# accessing a terminal in ubuntu via commadn line

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I have a couple of terminals open in Ubuntu (13.1). If I click on the terminal icon in the bar on the left side of the screen I can see all of them on my screen. However, with 1 open terminal I can't access it if I click on it in this setting (it just doen't appear after clicking on it although it is present in the view of all terminals). Is there any way to access this specific terminal through the comman line or to get a list of the terminals and then use the id (or something like this) to then somehow access it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's commands for that, i never had such trouble using more than 1 terminal , i  could always open them by clicking on left side of the screen...maybe alt-tab..

Comment: it normally worked for me as well but I am really desperate to retrieve this open terminal...